# neo4j service root does not show relationship URI

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to fetch a relationship, using its ID, back from Neo4j using py2neo. I am running into the problem described at the following link

https://github.com/nigelsmall/py2neo/issues/80

Basically, the neo4j API service root does not list the relationship URI.

So what is the preferred way to get back a relationship by ID, via the REST API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was fixed and released in py2neo 1.4.5 yesterday. Hope this helps!

Nige